# Funcion Auth no me funciona en Laravel php

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hice una autenticacion manual en Laravel 5.4 y no puedo conseguir que devuelva true la funcion.

En mi base de datos ingrese un registro desde el administrador de base de datos con username = admin y password = admin.(Tambien intenté creando el usuario y contraseña desde un formulario de laravel y nada)

aca dejo el codigo de mis archivos

LoginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

public function store( Request $request ){


    if(Auth::attempt(['username' => 'admin', 'password' => 'admin'])){
        return "ok";
    }else{
        return "error";
    }
}
}
```

Obviamente aqui estan hardcodeados el usuario y contraseña para no tener que ingresarlos una y otra vez.

Usuario.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticableTrait;

class Usuario extends Eloquent implements Authenticatable
{
use AuthenticableTrait;

protected $fillable = ['username', 'password'];

}
```

formulario de login

```
{!!Form::open(['route' => 'login.store' ,'method' => 'POST'])!!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {!!Form::label('Usuario')!!}
        {!!Form::text('user', null, ['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
    </div>        
    <div class="form-group">
        {!!Form::label('Contraseña')!!}
        {!!Form::password('password', ['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!!Form::submit('Ingresar', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-lg 
btn-block'])!!}
    </div>
    {!!Form::close()!!}
```

Se que a la funcion llega, ya que me esta devolviendo "error" como se puede ver en el logincontroller, en la parte del else.

Yo pienso que no esta comparando correctamente la contraseña ya que hice una prueba de cambiar el nombre de la columna 'username' en la base de datos y me tiro un error, pero al cambiar el nombre de la columna 'password' solo me devolvio false y ningun error de Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontre el problema, la contraseña debia estar encriptada en la base de datos.

La verdad que lo encontre en internet, en la seccion de authentication de la documentacion de laravel no vi que lo mencionara.

Comment: No es necesario mencionarlo, es implícito que las contraseñas van encriptadas.